# How to convert this data structure in python

Tags: python

I have the following Python structure.

```
{'2015-03-03': 
    [{'traffic': 80.0, 'Server': 'Server1'},
     {'traffic': 20.0, 'Server': 'Server2'}],
 '2015-03-04':
    [{'traffic': 100.0, 'Server': 'Server1'}]}
```

I need to convert this to a dictionary as

```
{"Series": 
    [{'traffic': [80.0, 20.0], 'Server': 'Server1'},
     {'traffic’: [100.0, 0], ’Server': 'Server2'}],
 "dates" : 
    [“2015-03-03”, 2015-03-04”]}
```

I tried the following. (result had the first dictionary)

```
final_data = {}
final_data['series'] = []
final_data['dates'] = sorted(result.keys())
for key in final_data['dates']:
    final_data['series'].append(result[key])
```

But this does not yield the converted data structure. Any help?

Comment: Have you got any code where you have attempted to do the conversion?

Comment: You have some holes and discrepancies between your source and your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
di = {
    '2015-03-03': [{'traffic': 80.0, 'Server': 'Server1'},
                   {'traffic': 20.0, 'Server': 'Server2'}],
    '2015-03-04': [{'traffic': 100.0, 'Server': 'Server1'}]
}


dates = sorted(di.keys())                                       # Get all dates
servers = set(e['Server'] for v in di.values() for e in v)      # Get all servers

# Refactor the dictionary
df = {}
for (k,v) in di.iteritems():
    df[k] = {}
    for elem in v:
        df[k][elem['Server']] = elem['traffic']

# Compute series (if the [date][server] key-chain doesn't exist in df, use 0)
series = []
for server in servers:
    traffic = []
    for date in dates:
        try:    traffic.append(df[date][server])
        except: traffic.append(0)
    series.append({'traffic':traffic, 'Server':server})

# Create output dict
do = {
    'Series': series,
    'dates': dates,
}

print do
```

Output:

```
{
    'Series': [
        {'traffic': [80.0, 100.0], 'Server': 'Server1'}, 
        {'traffic': [20.0, 0], 'Server': 'Server2'}
    ], 
    'dates': ['2015-03-03', '2015-03-04']
}
```

Note that *this differs from your expected output*.  In your expected output you had `do['Series'][0]['traffic'] = [80.0, 20.0]` but I have `[80.0, 100.0]` -- since they're the traffic entries corresponding to 'Server1'.

If you really want `[80.0, 20.0]`, I'm going to need to know what logic you're using to make that connection.